# Tensorflow cannot open libcuda.so.1

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, nvidia

I have a laptop with a GeForce 940 MX. I want to get Tensorflow up and running on the gpu. I installed everything from their tutorial page, now when I import Tensorflow, I get

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened  CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: workLaptop
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1092] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1093] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.367.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>>
```

after which I think it just switches to running on the cpu.

EDIT: After I nuked everything , started from scratch. Now I get this:

```
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: workLaptop
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1092] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1093] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.367.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

Comment: Have you actually installed the NVIDIA driver? libcuda is part of the driver, not the CUDA toolkit

Comment: Locate the file using `find /usr/ -name 'libcuda.so.1'` Is it in the standard cuda library directories i assume you added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? If not,  just create a symbolic link to it in cuda lib directory.

Comment: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 and 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1.  Where exactly is the cuda lib directory?

Comment: I will repeat ``could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version" means that you don't have a functional CUDA driver at the time you are running Tensorflow

Comment: reinstalled everything, updated the error

Comment: The error is still the same error and the problem is still the same problem.

Comment: So the solution is not the proposed one.

Comment: This does not look like a Tensorflow problem; instead, it looks like you don't have a correctly installed and running NVidia driver. One test: try running "nvidia-smi". It should print a list of the available GPUs if the driver is installed correctly.

Comment: Hi, did you managed to get it running on this GPU? I want to buy a laptop with it and wonder if it will work with tensorflow

Comment: @MosheKravchik , yes, I just had to reinstall CUDA and CUDNN. I does work but it's slow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

libcuda.so.1 is a symlink to a file that is specific to the version of your NVIDIA drivers.  It may be pointing to the wrong version or it may not exist.

```
# See where the link is pointing.  
ls  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 -la
# My result:
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Feb 22 20:40 \
# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 -> ./libcuda.so.375.39

# Make sure it is pointing to the right version. 
# Compare it with the installed NVIDIA driver.
nvidia-smi

# Replace libcuda.so.1 with a link to the correct version
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -f -s libcuda.so.<yournvidia.version> libcuda.so.1
```

Now in the same way, make another symlink from libcuda.so.1 to a link of the same name in your [LD_LIBRARY_PATH directory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#environment-setup).

You may also find that you need to create a link to libcuda.so.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu named libcuda.so

Comment: ***Now in the same way, make another symlink from libcuda.so.1 to a link of the same name in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH directory.*** How exactly is this done? What is my "LD_LIBRARY_PATH directory"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I faced the same issue. my Nvidia version is 450.216.04. How to write it? sudo ln -f -s libcuda.so.450.216.04  libcuda.so.1, reight?

Answer (score 17):

In case anyone still encounters this. First make sure to add the `--runtime=nvidia` parameter in order to run your container.

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu
```

where `tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu` is the name of the docker image.

Answer (score 8):

In the case I just solved, it was updating the GPU driver to the latest and installing the cuda toolkit. First, the ppa was added and GPU driver installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

After adding the ppa, it showed options for driver versions, and 390 was the latest 'stable' version that was shown.

Then install the cuda toolkit:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

It updated the drivers to a newer version than the 390 originally installed in the first step (it was 410; this was a p2.xlarge instance on AWS).